# DOTENV Windows Environment Variables but no others showing up

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm using Node and I installed `dotenv` on my PC and stored a dummy environment variable (API_KEY=43783283287) in the .env file.

Also consider the paths of the files below (if it helps):

- app.js is stored in bloccit/src/app.js
- .env is stored in bloccit/.env
- main-config.js is stored in bloccit\src\config\main-config.js

To get the full picture, this is also the code extract

main-config.js:

```
require("dotenv").config()
const path = require("path");
const viewsFolder = path.join(__dirname, "..", "views");
```

app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const appConfig = require("./config/main-config.js");

console.log(process.env); //returns windows environment variables
console.log(process.env.API_KEY); //returns undefined

const routeConfig = require("./config/route-config.js");

appConfig.init(app, express);
routeConfig.init(app);

module.exports = app;
```

.env:

```
API_KEY=43783283287
```

Problem: when I run my app.js file (which includes `console.log(process.env)`), I get a list of all my windows environment variables (see image attached below) but I do not see my API_KEY in the list.

Also, if I do `console.log(process.env.API_KEY)`, it returns `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: For one, you're not showing the code where you actually invoke dotenv. Because it's not going to add anything to `process.env` unless you actually load it.

Comment: Hi @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I included the code above to give you more context. When you say "invoke dotenv", do you mean to `require("dotenv").config()` ?

Comment: remember that dotenv tells you to "As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv" so make that line 1 in your app.js, not "a line in main-config". Also don't try to be clever in this case: `.env` file goes in your root dir, `app.js` goes in your root dir, and app.js gets `require("dotenv").config()`. If any of those things are not the case, you'll have to instruct dotenv on where to explicitly find the `.env` file it needs to load, which is usually completely unnecessary.

Comment: I can't see anything here that is a problem. Having the .env at root and app.js in src is OK. Can you confirm there is called ".env"

Comment: @Chev hi, yes I confirm you it is there and called ".env". To me, it really looks like that file is ignored, and the system shows only my PC environment variables

Comment: Hmm, can you share the cmd you using to start the app.

Comment: I actually fixed it! Thank @Chev, when you asked me about confirming if I had written ".env" I confirmed it, but then found out by running -ls a that it was saved as .env.env ... fixed that and now it works!

Comment: Cool, best of luck with the rest

Answer (score 3):

In my case, every time I tried to get a key from the .env file using process.env.MY_KEY, it returned undefined.

I suffered from this problem for two hours just because I named the file something like keys.env which is not considered to be a .env file.

So here is the troubleshooting list:

The filename should be .env (I believe .env.test is also acceptable).

Make sure you are requiring it as early as possible in your application using this statement `require('dotenv').config();`

The .env file should be in the root directory of your project.

Follow the "file writing rules" like `DB_HOST=localhost`, no need to wrap values in double/single quotes.

Also, check the documentation of the package on the NPM site.

Answer (score 0):

I use PM2 to run my apps and I faced exactly the same situation as you, guys. I've gotten `undefined` while trying to print/use the .env file.

In my case, the problem is that I was running `pm2 start` being outside of the 'dist' folder. For example: I was simply opening the Powershell and run `pm2 start C:\inetpub\wwwroot\node-apps\my-app\dist\index.js --name my-app`

Two hours later after some Googling, I realized what I was doing... (facepalm)
Once I ran `cd dist_path` before, and only then `pm2 start index.js --name=my=app`, it worked like a charm.

I hope it can help someone that my be facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `require('dotenv').config()` two directories above the root directory where the `.env` file is stored.

It should be

main-config.js

```js
const path = require("path");
require("dotenv").config({ path: path.join(__dirname, "../../") })
const viewsFolder = path.join(__dirname, "..", "views");
```

Answer (score 0):

my first answer here, none of the articles or tutorial tell us that the .env file should be named just only ".env" nothing more. so any filename like config.env, key.env will NOT work. As the top answer said, keep name only '.env'.
this goes for all programming languages Python, js etc.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other answers help, here's another thing to check: I had an issue where my `.env` file was saved with a whacky encoding. Changing it to utf-8 solved the issue.